# Tool for creating a text based list of changed files from a source tree?

Tags: windows, open-source, file-management, version-control, comparison

I am looking for a tool that can compare two source trees and output a list of changed files with their paths like shown below.  I have Araxis Merge today and use it for comparing and merging changes with other developers but when we check software into our repository tool we need a list of files to individually check in.  The repository tool does not integrate with our `IDE` so it's a manual process.  I'd just like a tool to build me a list of files that needs checked into the repository.  I will manually check them in and add the change reasons but would like a way to build the changed/added/deleted file list automatically if possible.

**Basically I have to input to the tool.**

1. Source tree #1 `(C:\sourcedir - rev1)`
2. Source tree #2 `(C:\sourcedir_rev - rev2)`

**And outputs a list like below....**

`C:\sourcedir\Include\myheader2.h`

`C:\sourcedir\Source\mysource2.c`

`C:\sourcedir\Configuration\myconfig2.ini`

`C:\sourcedir\Include\myheader1.h`

`C:\sourcedir\Source\mysource4.c`

`C:\sourcedir\Source\mysource5.c`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/)

Far Manager is one of the most powerful file management tools on Windows. It has a wide array of features. The most relevant ones to your question are:

- Comparing the files in two directories
- Recording macros so actions can be repeated with a single key combination

---

What follows are instructions on how to create a list of changed files:

1. Navigate to both folders using the two panels in Far Manager
2. Compare the folders using the sequence <kbd>F9</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

   - This will highlight the modified files in the right panel
3. Copy the highlighted file names using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>
4. Paste them in a text file (or write them using `echo` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> `> diff.txt`

Those were a lot of key presses, so it makes sense to create a shortcut for that. Here's how to do it:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to start recording the macro
2. Type the above steps
3. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to save the macro in a custom key combination. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for example.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to delete or change the macro. It should look like this:

```
Keys("F9 c c CtrlAltIns e c h o Space CtrlV Space > Space d i f f . t x t Enter")
```

Using your designated key combination, you should end up with a file named `diff.txt` which contains a list of the names of modified files in the right panel

---

More advance comparison options are available through the plug-in Advanced Compare, including specifying whether or not to check subfolders, and whether to base the results on size, contents, or both:

[image]

Other file and directory comparison plug-ins exist as well, namely [**Deep Compare**](http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php), and [**Visual Compare**](http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=856)

**Note:** Far Manager works best when used together with [**ConEmu**](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), which offers multi-tabs and other extended features.

Answer (score 0):

The command line `diff` tool can do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217628/diff-to-output-only-the-file-names

`diff -qr dir1 dir2`

Should do what you are after.

On windows you can use something like `cygwin` for this.